# store list from 2D array within For Next loop in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to be able to use my values from a column throughout my project. As of now I have read my file in a 2D array. I am working with 62 columns and roughly 200 rows. My issue is when I go through my array I can only access my last value. I am going to be using all values throughout my coding project weather it may be graphing and search. So I need to be able to come out of my for next loop with all values. I am using LineCount to count all the rows of my file due to it will change often. I also read my 2D array column as a string an converted it to a integer and then from scientific notation to a common number. I know I am missing something simple on storing the values before the last next loop but I can not figure it out for nothing any and all ideas welcome.

> ```
> Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("location.of.my.file.csv")
> for x101 = 1 to LineCount 
>    Dim data = lines(x101)
>    Dim splits = data.split(","c)
>    Dim StringConversion As Single
>
>    For y101 = 0 to 62
>       My2Darray(x101, y101) = splits(y101)
>       GrossGammaCounts = My2Darray(x101,44)
>    Next
>    StringConversion = CSng(GrossGammaCounts)
>    GrossGammaCounts = StringConversion
> Next
> MsgBox(GrossGammaCounts)
> ```

Comment: What is the `GrossGammaCounts = My2Darray(x101,44)` meant to do? If you are trying to sum up all values from column 44, use `GrossGammaCounts += My2Darray(x101,44)` and move it out of the `For y101` loop.

Comment: GrossGammaCounts = My2Darray(x101,44)

This is my portion of my array I just labeled x101 due to having so many I. Was working with it helped me keep track of the x’s. This just lets me only look in column 44 and read alll of the rows for that column I am using GrossGammaCounts as my variable that can be used throughout my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses Lists and sums up all the GammaCount values into your GammaCounts variable:

```
Dim rows As New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim GrossGammaCounts As Single = 0

Using reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("location.of.my.file.csv")

    With reader
        .TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        .SetDelimiters(",")
    End With

    Dim currentRow As String()

    While Not reader.EndOfData

        Try
            currentRow = reader.ReadFields()

            Dim fields As New List(Of String)
            For Each currentField As String In currentRow
                ' Add each column to line List
                fields.Add(currentField)
            Next

            ' Add row
            rows.Add(fields)

            ' Get GammaCount for this row, from field 44
            If currentRow.Count > 44 Then

                Dim rowGammaCount As String = currentRow(44)
                Dim StringConversion As Single = CSng(rowGammaCount)

                ' Update total
                GrossGammaCounts += StringConversion

            End If

        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While

End Using
```

You can access each value from your file using:

```
rows(rowNumber).Item(columnNumber)
```

For example, `rows(0).Item(44)` will return the first row's 45th column.

Comment: @Jimi thanks, answer updated to use TextFieldParser based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files).

Comment: Suggestion: remove the `If currentRow.Count > 44` condition and just add `GrossGammaCounts += CSng( currentRow(44))`: I think you want to throw in case the data row is malformed, so you know something went wrong there. Maybe handle the exception, so you throw a custom exception and message